# Square and cubic root of gaussian Integer

Tags: radicals, gaussian-integers

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate the Square-root (cube-root?)of an Gaussian integer n, where n isn't a square number.

So i define the integer square root of an gaussian-integer n as the largest number r (with respect to the norm) with $r^2$ <= n.

With n = c+di I am looking for the number r = a+bi with maximal norm $q = a^2+b^2$ where $q^2 \leqslant c^2 + d^2$.

Using $(a+bi)^2 = a^2 - b^2 + 2ab i$ and $a^2+b^2 = \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$ I get the following three equations:

a) $a^2-b^2 = c$

b) $d = 2ab$

c) $a^2+b^2 = \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$

Adding a) and c) I get

a') $2a^2 = c + \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$

Solving for a and b I get something like

$a = \sqrt \frac{(c + \sqrt{c^2+d^2})}{2}, b = \frac{d}{2a}$ ,

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate this value only in integer operations. And the obvious generalization to cubic roots and Eisenstein integers.

Everything I tried is numerically unstable. Is there any general approach?

Comment: What's wrong with computing the square root over  $\Bbb C$ as usual and then round to the nearest in $\Bbb Z[i]$?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, but: 
-I don't have a library for computing with floating point numbers of arbitrary length
- From a principal position I don't like to introduce algebraic numbers to solve a problem in integers.

Comment: So you want to swim but don't want to get wet... The formula in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratwurzel#Definition has terms like $\sqrt{\frac{z+|x|}2}$. You can use integer square root for that. But how are you expecting to compute something without computation?